# Detecting optimum number of lines using Hough Transform

Tags: matlab, hough-transform

I want that my routine would detect exactly that many lines which are available in an image.

The following code works fine to detect lines from an image,

```
clear_all();

image_name = 'hough1.png';
% no of  pixels discarded on border areas
pixel_count = 10;
% select largest 1 peaks
maxPeaks = 1;
% maximum allowed gap between lines
fillgap = 500;
% the minimum length of a line 
minline = 7;

% read image and convert to grayscale
input_image = gray_imread(image_name);
% discard border area
input_image = discard_image_area(input_image, pixel_count);
% create a binary image
binary_image = edge(input_image,'canny');    
% extract Hough Features
[H,T,R] = hough(binary_image); 

% identify peaks in Hough Data
threshPeaks = ceil(0.3*max(H(:)));
P  = houghpeaks(H, maxPeaks, 'threshold', threshPeaks);

% extract lines
hough_lines = houghlines(binary_image,T,R,P,'FillGap',fillgap,'MinLength',minline);   

draw_hough_lines('Detected Hough Lines', input_image, hough_lines);
```

If we use the following image as our **input**,

[image]

The **output** becomes,

[image]

**This routine has a big issue in that it always detects `maxPeaks` number of line(s).**

Suppose, we have a picture (as above) where we don't know how many lines are there. Then, **how can we detect all of the lines?**

For instance, if we set `maxPeaks = 5`, the routine will detect 2 lines from the following image.

**Input**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

**How can I solve this issue?**

Comment: You want to remove duplicate lines?

Comment: You can try to change the peak threshold or remove lines that are merge lines that are too close.

Comment: @MimSaad, I want to remove duplicate lines, and I also want that my routine doesn't select an excessive number of unneeded lines.